# How to prove graph also has a cycle of length $a + b-2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

If an undirected graph contains two cycles of lengths $a, b$ respectively, that have exactly one edge in common. How can I prove that the graph also has a cycle of length
$a + b-2$.

Comment: $a  + b - 2 = (a - 1) + (b-1)$. Draw a picture!

Comment: what will be the reason to subtract 1 from each length

Comment: Follow one cycle, but *without* the common edge (start at one end, end at the other). Now ...

Comment: e.g. Taking a square with  $ABCD$ with diagonal $AC$. So we have 2 cycles (1)  $ABCA$   (2) $ADCA$  Now If I take 2 cycles separately and remove the common edge i.e. $AC$, So we get (1) $ABC$  (2) $ADC$  and now if we join we get a cycle $ABCD$, Please reply if my understanding to your reply is not correct.

Comment: Something along those lines, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a square  with vertices $ABCD$ with diagonal $AC$

[image]

Now it has 2 cycles   (So here 2 cycles a and b with 1 edge common)

(1) $ABC$  and  (2) $ADC$

[image] [image]

Now we subtract the common edge AC from both, we get  i.e. $( a-1, b-1$ )

[image][image]

Combining both we get a cycle with   $(a-1)+(b-1) = a+b-2$

[image]